# String split on new line, tab and some number of spaces

Tags: python, regex, split

I'm trying to perform a string split on a set of somewhat irregular data that looks something like:

```
\n\tName: John Smith
\n\t  Home: Anytown USA
\n\t    Phone: 555-555-555
\n\t  Other Home: Somewhere Else
\n\t Notes: Other data
\n\tName: Jane Smith
\n\t  Misc: Data with spaces
```

I'd like to convert this into a tuple/dict where I later will split on the colon `:`, but first I need to get rid of all the extra whitespace. I'm guessing a regex is the best way but I can't seem to get one that works, below is my attempt.

```
data_string.split('\n\t *')
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Just use [.strip()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip), it removes all whitespace for you, including tabs and newlines, while splitting. The splitting itself can then be done with [`data_string.splitlines()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines):

```
[s.strip() for s in data_string.splitlines()]
```

Output:

```
>>> [s.strip() for s in data_string.splitlines()]
['Name: John Smith', 'Home: Anytown USA', 'Phone: 555-555-555', 'Other Home: Somewhere Else', 'Notes: Other data', 'Name: Jane Smith', 'Misc: Data with spaces']
```

You can even inline the splitting on `:` as well now:

```
>>> [s.strip().split(': ') for s in data_string.splitlines()]
[['Name', 'John Smith'], ['Home', 'Anytown USA'], ['Phone', '555-555-555'], ['Other Home', 'Somewhere Else'], ['Notes', 'Other data'], ['Name', 'Jane Smith'], ['Misc', 'Data with spaces']]
```

Comment: That worked wonderfully, the syntax of the [List comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) wasn't something I'd seen before so I supposed I'll have to read up on it.

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> for line in s.splitlines():
...     line = line.strip()
...     if not line:continue
...     ary.append(line.split(":"))
...
>>> ary
[['Name', ' John Smith'], ['Home', ' Anytown USA'], ['Misc', ' Data with spaces'
]]
>>> dict(ary)
{'Home': ' Anytown USA', 'Misc': ' Data with spaces', 'Name': ' John Smith'}
>>>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can kill two birds with one regex stone:

```
>>> r = """
... \n\tName: John Smith
... \n\t  Home: Anytown USA
... \n\t    Phone: 555-555-555
... \n\t  Other Home: Somewhere Else
... \n\t Notes: Other data
... \n\tName: Jane Smith
... \n\t  Misc: Data with spaces
... """
>>> import re
>>> print re.findall(r'(\S[^:]+):\s*(.*\S)', r)
[('Name', 'John Smith'), ('Home', 'Anytown USA'), ('Phone', '555-555-555'), ('Other Home', 'Somewhere Else'), ('Notes', 'Other data'), ('Name', 'Jane Smith'), ('Misc', 'Data with spaces')]
>>>
```

Comment: Pretty good, but your `[ \t]*` isn't doing anything; the `(.+)` will always eat the trailing whitespace if there is any.  You could do this instead: `(.+?)[ \t]*$`.  The reluctant quantifier allows it to stop early, while the `$` makes sure it still consumes the whole line.

Answer (score 5):

If you look at [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) for `str.split`:

> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently, splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace with a None separator returns [].

In other words, if you're trying to figure out what to pass to `split` to get `'\n\tName: Jane Smith'` to `['Name:', 'Jane', 'Smith']`, just pass nothing (or None).

This almost solves your whole problem. There are two parts left.

First, you've only got two fields, the second of which can contain spaces. So, you only want one split, not as many as possible. So:

```
s.split(None, 1)
```

Next, you've still got those pesky colons. But you don't need to split on them. At least given the data you've shown us, the colon always appears at the end of the first field, with no space before and always space after, so you can just remove it:

```
key, value = s.split(None, 1)
key = key[:-1]
```

There are a million other ways to do this, of course; this is just the one that seems closest to what you were already trying.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
string.strip().split(":")
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex's aren't really the best tool for the job here. As others have said, using a combination of `str.strip()` and `str.split()` is the way to go. Here's a one liner to do it:

```
>>> data = '''\n\tName: John Smith
... \n\t  Home: Anytown USA
... \n\t    Phone: 555-555-555
... \n\t  Other Home: Somewhere Else
... \n\t Notes: Other data
... \n\tName: Jane Smith
... \n\t  Misc: Data with spaces'''
>>> {line.strip().split(': ')[0]:line.split(': ')[1] for line in data.splitlines() if line.strip() != ''}
{'Name': 'Jane Smith', 'Other Home': 'Somewhere Else', 'Notes': 'Other data', 'Misc': 'Data with spaces', 'Phone': '555-555-555', 'Home': 'Anytown USA'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to split a string on newline (\n) and tab (\t). What I did was first to replace \n by \t and then split on \t

```py
example_arr = example_string.replace("\n", "\t").split("\t")
```